# System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext Timeout Property is Not Working

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am having an issue where a query times out prior to retrieving results.  I am using Entity Framework   v. 6.0.  Setting the context.Timeout property doesn't seem to have any affect.

Here is the class declaration and constructor so you know what I'm dealing with.  It's generated code from the Reference.cs:

```
    public partial class PSIDevEntities : global::System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize a new PSIDevEntities object.
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Services.Design", "1.0.0")]
    public PSIDevEntities(global::System.Uri serviceRoot) : 
            base(serviceRoot, global::System.Data.Services.Common.DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3)
    {
        this.ResolveName = new global::System.Func<global::System.Type, string>(this.ResolveNameFromType);
        this.ResolveType = new global::System.Func<string, global::System.Type>(this.ResolveTypeFromName);
        this.OnContextCreated();
        this.Format.LoadServiceModel = GeneratedEdmModel.GetInstance;
    }
```

I have tried setting the Timeout to a high number.  However, the query times out after 30 seconds.

```
var context = new PSIDevEntities(URI);
context.Timeout = 120000;
var result = from p in context.vwPacings
             where p.InactiveDateTime == null
             orderby p.ProgramTitle
             select p;
// timeout occurs here after 30 seconds
retList = result.ToList();
```

Somewhere, there is a default timeout of 30 seconds.  What do I need to do to increase the timeout for this query?

Comment: Is this really that difficult?  It must be something simple that I'm overlooking.

Comment: What exact error you receive? Docs says that this is HTTP timeout, but you may receive error from SQL query...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to modify the auto-generated code in the data service.  Yikes!  But it works.  To change the command timeout for the dataservice.  Enter these two lines into the constructor of the DbContext:

```
        var objectContext = (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
        objectContext.CommandTimeout = 120;   // Or any required timeout
```

So for my fix my constructor now looks like this:

```
public partial class PSIDevEntities : DbContext
{
    public PSIDevEntities()
        : base("name=PSIDevEntities")
    {
        base.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        var objectContext = (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
        objectContext.CommandTimeout = 120;
    }
...
```